# C++ read from file, skipping some information

Tags: c++, file-io

I need a way of reading the following file:

```
This is a line but not needed
This is another line not needed
name   telephone
john   0000001
mark   0000002
.
.
.
```

I want to skip the very first lines, and the thrid line the headers.
I want to save the names in a string variable and the telephone as well in a string variable.
There are tabs between the data.

So this is my code but won't work.

```
string line; 
while (getline(infile, line)) 
{
  istringstream iss(line);
  int a, b; 
  if (!(iss >> a >> b)) 
  { break; } // error 

  // process pair (a,b) 
}
```

So I would like to know how to skip some information like the header and to parse the information in variables.
Cheers.

Comment: How about to use `getline` or `ignore` for 3 times before processing?

Comment: yes but how I will ignore for 3 times? and then how I will now when a new line has changed?

Comment: I think you can find a pattern which can tell header and information, pick out the changeable part and define them as consts, or load them at runtime from environment.

Answer (score 0):

How about you keep reading from the file but only start storing into a string after you have read telephone!

Something like this:

```
string str, newStr;
boolean = false;
while(cin >> str){
    if(str.compare("telephone")== 0)
        boolean = true;
    if(boolean)
        newStr += str;
}
return newStr;
```

make sure to include string for the compare method

Comment: This print and the telephone as well, but also i lose track when line is changed.